# How to find area under the curve of functions whose integrals does not exist?

Tags: calculus, soft-question

We know that some functions such as $x^x$ do not have anti-derivatives. But, just because such functions do not have anti derivatives, does that mean we simply cannot find the area under the graph? Or are there any methods in calculus that can be used to find the area under the curve of such functions which cannot be integrated.

Edit: In this context, let us consider a non integrable function as one which does not have a closed form of an anti derivative.

Comment: When you say, "they can't be integrated" I assume you mean that we can't find a closed form formula for the antiderivative.  In that case, we have to use numerical methods to approximate the integral.  You should learn simple methods, like the trapezoidal rule and Simpson's rule in your calculus course.  There are far more sophisticated methods available, of course.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration

Comment: If you have a continuous function on some interval, and you want to find the area within that interval, it always exist... The function doesn't need to have an explicit anti-derivative. That is you might not be able to write the anti-derivative as some elementary functions (so you can apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus). However, as commented by @saulspatz, one can always do it numerically. There are many numerical methods to do this as you have learned in Cal 1. Trapazoid, Simpson's, Gaussian quadrature method, etc.

Comment: Some "famous" functions were created to represent the integral of a function whose antiderivative wasn't otherwise expressible. So you can always "cheat" and create your own function that represents the integral of x^x-- it doesn't count as closed form, but like many similar functions, you can still evaluate it.

Comment: $x^x$ has an anti-derivative. In particular, $f(x) = \int_1^x t^t\,dt$ is one such anti-derivative. Note that the integral is defined by a limit, not by means of anti-derivatives. It exists for all continuous functions and the integral above will define a differentiable function whose derivative is the integrand. Thus all continuous functions have an anti-derivative. That anti-derivative isn't always expressible by elementary functions and operations (i.e., "doesn't always have a closed form). But it still a well-defined function (up to an added constant).